# dprintf implicit declaration warning

Tags: c, warnings, implicit-declaration

When using [dprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) I'm getting the warning "implicit declaration of dprintf". That tends to mean a necessary file isn't included, but I already included stdio.h, which is supposed to be all that it needs. Is there something else dprintf needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "feature_test_macros" section of the man page explains that to make stdio.h declare dprintf(), you must first `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` (or higher) before you `#include <stdio.h>`.  The reason for this is that dprintf() was not standardized until POSIX.1-2008, but `<stdio.h>` needs to continue to work with code written before that, even if that code used its own identifier named "dprintf".  (Defining _GNU_SOURCE or _XOPEN_SOURCE would also work on Linux, but _POSIX_C_SOURCE is the best choice for general portability.)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set some macros. Put on top of the file, before any `include`s the following

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

(One of that would be enough but I don't know the GLibC version you use)

Comment: Or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`.  Or `-std=gnu11`.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @JonathanLeffler : `-std=gnu11` is the option for GCC not to be put on top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up for `fprintf()` [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf).

I ran into the same problem and hence I was forced to run on POSIX based machine, I must changed my code, so `fprintf()` is one of (may be) many options I had.
example :

```
fprintf(stderr,"file not found");
```